# Canvas.getBufferStrategy() VS JPanel.paintComponent(Graphics g)

Tags: java, canvas, graphics, jpanel

What is the difference between `Canvas.getBufferStrategy()` and `JPanel.paintComponent(Graphics g)`

I am more familiar with the `JPanel` stuff but I am clueless about the canvas bufferstrategy.

I looked online and there are not very many comparisons between the two.

Which one is better for 2D or 3D?

Thanks

Comment: The core difference is in the paint system.  Swing has it's own paint system which is responsible for scheduling and managing paint cycles, it employs a passive approach to the painting (essentially a paint on demand) where as `BufferStrategy` hands complete control of the paint system to you and is what is considered a active painting system. Neither is better for 3D as neither actually support it, you'll need to use a third party Api for that

Comment: Both are good at 2D graphics, but if you want control over the paint system, then you need to use a `BufferStrategy`. Note that they are incompatible with each other, you can't (easily) render Swing components using a `BufferStrategy` and `Canvas` can cause issue with Swing hierarchies

Comment: You might also consider having a look at [Difference between using Canvas and JPanel for a 2D game engine (and Buffering?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441169/difference-between-using-canvas-and-jpanel-for-a-2d-game-engine-and-buffering/43442434#43442434)

Comment: @MadProgrammer What do you mean by 'complete control'. What advantages does it have over JPanel?

Comment: Swing employees a `RepaintManager` which makes decisions about what and when a paint cycle takes place, this can interfere with systems which require/desire a constant frame rate or want to control what get's painted and when

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for answering my question and keeping it simple :)